# Query mysql with hard concatenament

Tags: php, mysql

i need to help from you, this is my problem:

I have 2 table

```
Friends
----------------------------------------
friends_club_1 | friends_club_2 | state
1234                 4321          1
2345                 1234          1
1234                 4567          1
4569                 1567          1



  User Info
  -----------------------------------------------
    id  |    name    |    surname     |    age   |
   2345     Jhonny         Jenny           24
   4567     Linda          Minda           23
   1567     Stefan         Refan           25
   1234     me             me              23
   4569     dani           mari            28
   4321     Star           Gate            24
```

I would like have the follow result:

```
Result
-----------------------------------------------------
my_friends   | state |  name  | surname | age

4321           1        Star       Gate    24
2345           1        Jhonny    Jenny    24
4567           1        Linda     Minda    23
1567           1        Stefan    Refan    25

ecc....
```

I would like have this result knowing the me id 1234
I hope one help thank you so much

Comment: According to your desired result `Stefan` should be in the result but in your example tables he is not friends with `me`. Is this a mistake or are you trying to get friends and friends of friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results aren't correct, "Stefan Refan" wouldn't be in the results.

```
SELECT UI.id AS my_friends,
       COALESCE(F1.state,F2.state) AS state,
       UI.name, UI.surname, UI.age
FROM [User Info] as UI
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Friends] AS F1 ON (UI.id = F1.friends_club_1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Friends] AS F2 ON (UI.id = F2.friends_club_2)
WHERE COALESCE(F1.friends_club_2,F2.friends_club_1) = 1234;
```

You would need to Coalesce the F1.state and F2.state to find which one is used.

Comment: Thank you it's right the query, but if i want add the filter show the result only with state = 1 how can i do that? i've tried but without succes

Comment: Add to the WHERE section `AND COALESCE(F1.state,F2.state) = 1`

Comment: I found now one error not found very good, sometimes not show the right result when i have more same id in the database

Comment: Could you clarify the error your getting? When you have duplicate ids?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like

```
SELECT UserInfo.*
FROM UserInfo
LEFT JOIN Friends ON (UserInfo.id IN (friends_club1, friends_club2))
WHERE UserInfo.id = 1234
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT u.id AS my_friends  ,u.state,  u.name,  u.surname , u.age FROM user_info u
INNER JOIN friends f1(u.id = f1.friends_club_1)
INNER JOIN friends f2(u.id = f2.friends_club_2)
WHERE f1.friends_club_1=1234 OR  f2.friends_club_2=1234
```

OR by subquery you can do it like

```
SELECT u.id AS my_friends  ,u.state,  u.name,  u.surname , u.age FROM user_info u
WHERE u.id IN(SELECT friends_club_1 FROM friends WHERE friends_club_2=1234) OR
u.id IN(SELECT friends_club_2 FROM friends WHERE friends_club_1=1234)
```

Hope it makes sense

> Note: Don't use the spaces in the column names and the table name

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` to link the tables together combined with a `UNION` to handle both cases of friends.

```
SELECT uf.*, f.state
FROM User_Info u
INNER JOIN Friends f
  ON f.friends_club_1 = u.id
INNER JOIN User_Info uf
  ON uf.id = f.friends_club_2
WHERE u.id = 1234

UNION

SELECT uf.*, f.state
FROM User_Info u
INNER JOIN Friends f
  ON f.friends_club_2 = u.id
INNER JOIN User_Info uf
  ON uf.id = f.friends_club_1
WHERE u.id = 1234
```